# Matrix Islands Generation Algorithm JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

I was trying to work out how to generate random islands of `1`s in a sea of `0`s for a game a bit like battleships. My initial thoughts were to count the number of neighbors for given conditions. For example, islands of size 1 have zero neighbors. Islands of 2 have exactly one neighbor for each cell. Then I thought maybe I could recursively check if each new cell touched an existing island.

I then investigated existing solutions only to find that finding such islands is a fairly standard algorithmic problem, solved by depth-first search.

However, the problem of generating such islands is not well documented. For example if I want 2 islands of 1 cell, 2 of 2 cells and one of 3, how would I go about this?

For evidence of initial labour, I built this app to help count neighbors for given conditions: http://balanceit.one/dev/matrix-islands/

I don't know how useful might be in this solution, but it gave me a starting point.

Perhaps the solution involves generating random configurations until until one fits the requirements? Would that be a viable approach or is there a more deterministic approach to this problem?

As always, any help much appreciated.

Comment: i guess u need to consider the islands as a group of cells rather than 1 cell making one island, there can be an island made of 2 cell together or 3 cell together, so in the logic for creating island and reading the neighbor by sending the island coordinate has to be passed through a filter function which aggregates the coordinates (cell) to return the island as a group of cell, then pass it to the neighbour() to find its neibour

Comment: Do you need to have the islands of a specific size (e.g. size 2), or you just want them to "look natural", like a geographical map, with random variations in size and shape?

Comment: Specific. Like battleships with a set number of different size ships, but with groups of `1`s representing people, and not just in straight lines.